# No Display Output using i915 and modeset(0): failed to set mode: No such file or directory

Tags: xorg, display

I'm working with a display and getting the following results, all using Ubuntu 22.04 (I've also tried all in Manjaro with same results):

- AMD graphics card system (amdgpu driver) display functions normally
- Intel integrated graphics computer (i915 driver) gets no display
- Raspberry Pi (?? driver) gets no display

For the AMD system (working), I can run `xrandr --verbose` and get the modeline:

`Modeline "2880x1920"x0.0  360.23  2880 2928 2960 3040  1920 1925 1930 1975 +hsync -vsync (118.5 kHz eP)`

Running `xrandr` on the Intel system i get:

```
HDMI-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1280x720      60.00    50.00  
   720x480       59.94
```

Not seeing the correct output resolution, I follow the advice of other posts and try to add the modeline manually using:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "2880x1920" 360.23 2880 2928 2960 3040 1920 1925 1930 1976 +hsync -vsync
$ xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 2880x1920
$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 2880x1920 --verbose
```

Results:

```
screen 0: 2880x1920 760x506 mm  96.25dpi
crtc 0:    2880x1920  60.00 +0+0 "HDMI-1"
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
crtc 0: disable
screen 0: revert
crtc 0: revert
```

I checked the log with `cat ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log`

```
[   717.472] (II) modeset(0): Allocate new frame buffer 2880x1920 stride
[   717.588] (EE) modeset(0): failed to set mode: No such file or directory
[   717.608] (II) modeset(0): Allocate new frame buffer 1280x720 stride
[   717.759] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 1713
[   717.759] (II) modeset(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[   717.759] (II) modeset(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[   717.759] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   717.759] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "2880x1920"x0.0  360.23  2880 2928 2960 3040  1920 1925 1930 1975 +hsync -vsync (118.5 kHz eP)
[   717.759] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
```

On the Intel computer, the second line reads as reported in the log, for RPi, it says

```
  2302.315] (EE) modeset(0): failed to set mode: Invalid argument
```

Otherwise the results are the same.

Looking at this log, even without adding the `xrandr --newmode`, teh display is self reporting the correct resolution and timings of 2880x1920.  However, for some reason, even though it is self reported and the other mode shows up, `xrandr` does not report this mode as being available until I add it manually.  And after manually adding, I cannot use this mode and modeset claims it is invalid, even though it works on another system.

Is this a bug in modesetting? can I force a different driver to function?

Comment: You didn't specify what 22.04 media you tried (*there are numerous*); I assume it was media using the 5.15 GA kernel stack; but if it was me I'd try 22.10 with 5.19 kernel stack (*or 22.04.2 RC media that contains that same 5.19 stack*) as booting *live* media is quick & easy (*also helps that I have it here within reach too*).

Comment: On my intel platform I tried both 5.15 and 5.19.  Same results.  I also wondered if it was a kernel issue, but neither fixed.